# Breaking a stick twice - why are $Y$ and $\frac{X}{Y}$ are independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

A stick of length $L$ is broken at a point which is chosen according to a uniform distribution. We keep the left 'substick' of length $Y$.

Then we, in turn, break this 'substick' and keep another left part which is $X$.

The book says that r.v.'s $Y$ and $X/Y$ are independent, but I don't understand why. I could use the definition of independence but I can't find the necessary PDFs for that and the book doesn't do that either, just states the fact.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is implicit in the description of the mechanism that, conditionally on $Y$, $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,Y)$. Thus, conditionally on $Y$, $X/Y$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. This last conditional distribution does not depend on $Y$ hence $X/Y$ is independent of $Y$.

Comment: @Did So are $Y$ and $X/Y$ independent because for any given $Y=y$ $X/Y$ is distributed on (0,1)?

Comment: Yes, with the same distribution.

Comment: Yes. Another way of putting this is that $P(X/Y\leq r\mid Y=y)=r$ for all $r,y\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys.